# cc, bcc, problems in google script --

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This script worked fine until today, when I added cc and bcc variables to the automated email script. Now, I'm getting an error with the recipient email addresses, and I think I also have a problem with the object for options cc and bcc. There error is an invalid email address, with and without cc and bcc. That is, somehow I broke the script, and even the old version doesn't work--did google update something? Any help is much appreciated.

```
function sendEmails1() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Send-Emails"));
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:O10");
var data = dataRange.getValues();


for (i in data) {   
var rowData = data[i];
var build = rowData[0];
var emailAddress1 = rowData[1];
var emailAddress2 = rowData[2];
var emailAddress3 = rowData[3];
var emailAddress4 = rowData[4];
var cc1 = rowData[11];
var cc2 = rowData[12];
var bcc1 = rowData[13];
var bcc2 = rowData[14];
var options = { 
  cc: "'" + cc1 + "," +  cc2 + "'" , 
  bcc: "'" + bcc1 + "," +  bcc2 + "'" 
}



var recipient = rowData[5];
var text2 = rowData[6]; 
var signoff = 'text';

var message = recipient + ', ' + text2 + signoff + '\n\n' + sender;
var subject = 'text';



//prompt the user with the composed email for review
var confirm = Browser.msgBox('Send the following email?', 'text', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);

if(confirm === 'yes'){

MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress1 + "," + emailAddress2 + "," + emailAddress3 + "," + emailAddress4, subject, message, options);

}
```

Comment: The string that the options variable creates is incorrect. Sometimes a bcc and cc will be undefined, as that cell in the google sheet is blank, maybe it's not possible to solve it this way.

Comment: I couldn't find a solution online using variables that may be undefined, so I reorganized the cc block to fixed email addresses that can't be change without changing the script, there's a fair amount of documentation on that online already available. Would be nice to see it the other way though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My script for draft writing with no receiver had the same problem, returning an undefined error when the cell was empty. I wrote in a test for blank cells, and if so, put 'null' in the parameter. Now my script works:

```
if(recipient==""){GmailApp.createDraft(null, sub, null, {cc: seesee, bcc: 
                   beeseesee, htmlBody: body1});}
else{
  GmailApp.createDraft(recipient, sub,null, {cc: seesee, bcc: beeseesee, 
 htmlBody: body1}); }
```

Where recipient, seesee, sub, body1, and beeseesee are my variables.

Answer (score 0):

This code script in Google scripts helps to create a draft email in Gmail with cc, so I hope it helps someone.

```
function myFunction() {
  // The code below creates a draft email with the current date and time.
var now = new Date();
  var ccmail = "dummy@gmail.com"
  GmailApp.createDraft("main@gmail.com,", "current time", "The time is: " + 
now.toString(), {cc: ccmail} );
}
```